# arithmetic significance of coefficients in a power series

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, soft-question, power-series, generating-functions

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3423458/583016) user @JackD'Aurizio said

> $$\frac{1}{1-x^3-x^4-x^{20}}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(x^3+x^4+x^{20})^k $$
>   and the coefficient of $x^{46}$ in $(x^3+x^4+x^{20})^k$ is the cardinality of the $k$-tuples with coordinates in $\{3,4,20\}$ such that the sum of the coordinates equals $46$.

and that made me really intrigued. Previously, I had only considered the significance of the coefficients of such a power series to be that they satisfied a certain recurrence relation. This new way of thinking about the coefficients if much more number-theoretic and interesting.

Certainly there is a more general theory behind this line of thought. What is it? Could I have some links where I could learn more? Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is quite common for example when arguing why the coefficients in the binomial theorem correspond to the combinatorial binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

[Polya, Szego - Problems and theorems in Analysis I](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=varVBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=poyla+sgezo+problems+and+theoems+in+analysis+i&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_mZqy_tPlAhWPfH0KHTy_Cm8Q6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q&f=false), part one, chapter $1$ - operations with power series.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it's a radical way to think about numbers and functions!  It's called a [Generating Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).  Many resources related to generating functions can be found in the answers to this question: [How can I learn about generating functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3142386/how-can-i-learn-about-generating-functions/3142387)

At the risk of being repetitious, here is an anecdote about the statistician Frederick Mosteller's first encounter with generating functions.

> A key moment in my life occurred in one of those classes during my
>   sophomore year. We had the question: When three dice are rolled what
>   is the chance that the sum of the faces will be 10? The students in
>   this course were very good, but we all got the answer largely by
>   counting on our fingers. When we came to class, I said to the teacher,
>   "That's all very well - we got the answer - but if we had been asked
>   about six dice and the probability of getting 18, we would still be
>   home counting. How do you do problems like that?" He said, "I don't
>   know, but I know a man who probably does and I'll ask him." One day I
>   was in the library and Professor Edwin G Olds of the Mathematics
>   Department came in. He shouted at me, "I hear you're interested in the
>   three dice problem." He had a huge voice, and you know how libraries
>   are. I was embarrassed. "Well, come and see me," he said, and I'll
>   show you about it." "Sure, " I said. But I was saying to myself, "I'll
>   never go." Then he said, "What are you doing?" I showed him. "That's
>   nothing important," he said. "Let's go now."
>
> So we went to his office, and he showed me a generating function. It
>   was the most marvelous thing I had ever seen in mathematics. It used
>   mathematics that, up to that time, in my heart of hearts, I had
>   thought was something that mathematicians just did to create homework
>   problems for innocent students in high school and college. I don't
>   know where I had got ideas like that about various parts of
>   mathematics. Anyway, I was stunned when I saw how Olds used this
>   mathematics that I hadn't believed in. He used it in such an unusually
>   outrageous way. It was a total retranslation of the meaning of the
>   numbers. [Albers, *More Mathematical People*].